# Adding multiple quadratic terms to objective function in Gurobi Python

Tags: python, gurobi

I'd like to set up an objective function in Gurobi to minimize `x^2 + y^2`. I've done my best to provide an example below:

```
import gurobipy as gbPy

model = gbPy.Model()

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B = [1, 2, 3]
x = model.addVars(5, lb = 0)
y = model.addVars(3, lb = 0)

for i in range(len(x)):
    model.addConstr(x[i] >= A[i])

for i in range(len(y)):
    model.addConstr(y[i] >= B[i])

objExp = gbPy.QuadExpr()

objExp.addTerms(???)
model.setObjective(objExp, gbPy.GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

But I'm not sure how to indicate the expression I want in the objExp.addTerms line. http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_quadexpr_add.html provides an example:

```
expr = x * x + 2 * y * y
expr.add(z * z, 3.0)
```

But I don't understand if it's adding 3*z^2 or z^2 + 3 to the expression. Any help in explaining the syntax is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that -- in your example -- you want to set the objective to minimize `x[0]^2 + y[0]^2`. It should be straight-forward to adapt this if you need a different objective.

There are various ways to set the objective.

You can define it directly inside `setObjective`:

```
model.setObjective(x[0] * x[0] + y[0] * y[0])
```

or

```
model.setObjective(x[0] * x[0] + y[0] * y[0], gbPy.GRB.MINIZE) # minimize is the default; so it is optional
```

This is the easiest and unless your objective expression is very long and unwieldy this is what I would recommend.

Or you can build the expression first. This can give a performance advantage if you are lots of terms.

```
# define the quadratic expression object
objExp = gbPy.QuadExpr()

# add single terms using add
objExp.add(x[0] * x[0]) 
objExp.add(y[0] * y[0])
# you could also do this in one line adding x[0]*x[0] + y[0]*y[0]

# or add multiple terms at once using addTerms
#objExp.addTerms([1, 1], [x[0], y[0]], [x[0], y[0]])

# set the objective
model.setObjective(objExp, gbPy.GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

Note that in this example both the parts with `add` and `addTerms` do the same. You would only need one.

The `add` method adds the expression in the first argument multiplied by the (optional) second argument. The example you are quoting first defines the expression `x^2 + y^2`, then adds `3z^2`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Silke! To confirm I understand `addTerms`, does your expression above return `1*x[0]*x[0] + 1*y[0]*y[0]` ?

Comment: Yes! The first array contains the coefficients, the second the first variables and the third the second variables of each term.