# Add many quadratic terms in Gurobi objective function

Tags: python, gurobi

I have a big objective function with many decision variables. That is, $$\sum_{i=0}^100 Z_i^2$$.  I want to know if there is an efficient way to add multiple quadratic terms in the objective function, or to construct a quadratic expression with many terms effectively, such as the build-in method addConstrs () for linear constraints.

In the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362487/adding-multiple-quadratic-terms-to-objective-function-in-gurobi-python), only a few quadratic terms are added. The straightforward extension would be to run a loop to add quadratic terms one by one.

Comment: I think my response answers the question or at least comes close. FYI, there is a [stackexchange site for OR](https://or.stackexchange.com/), in case you have more questions about Gurobi in the future.

Comment: @brentertainer I agree. I think the approach using quicksum function might be what I am looking for unless Gurobi supports the input of a matrix of coefficients.  Thank you for reminding me about the OR section.

Comment: There _are_ ways to do that (e.g. with numpy). What type of object do you use to store your coefficients?

Comment: I use numpy multi-dimension array to store my coefficients. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, thank you. See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gurobipy` package generally plays well with Python's comprehension syntax and built-ins, and variable sets are instances of dictionaries. So you could do:

```
model = gurobipy.Model()
x = model.addVars(100)
model.update()
obj = sum(variable * variable for variable in x.values())
```

OR

```
obj = sum(x[i] * x[i] for i in x.keys())
```

OR (if you really have lots and lots and lots of variables):

```
obj = gurobipy.quicksum(x[i] * x[i] for i in x.keys())
```

---

**EDIT**

If you need to incorporate coefficients from a numpy array, here are examples of how that can be done. The key is creating a numpy-compliant container for your variables first. Then most of the arithmetic numpy operations can be applied.

```
model = gurobipy.Model()
x = model.addVars(100)
model.update()

# make numpy-compliant container for x
x_np = np.array([x[i] for i in range(100)])

# 2-D matrix of random coefficients
Q = np.random.random(size=(100, 100))

# 1-D vector of random coefficients
c = np.random.random(size=100)

# x^T * Q * x
expr = np.sum(Q * np.outer(x_np, x_np))

# (diagonal of Q) * x
expr = np.dot(Q.diagonal(), x_np)

# c * x
expr = np.dot(c, x_np)
```